# How to index apache nutch fetched content without parsing into solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I need to index fetched content crawled by nutch into solr. Solrjob in nutch indexes only parse content. And i need the content with all HTML tags. Can anyone guide me on this?

Thanks
Sudh

Answer (score 2):

Nutch has a series of parsers and filters that will extract content from the fetched HTML.

You need to implement an HtmlParserFilter, write the raw content into a metatag and insert it into a SOLR field.

The tutorial below is about an indexing filter but it follows the same flow.

[Nutch plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample)

Your class should implement "HtmlParseFilter" instead of "IndexingFilter".
override the filter() method:

```
@Override
public ParseResult filter(Content content, ParseResult parseResult, HTMLMetaTags metaTags, DocumentFragment doc) {
    Metadata metadata = parseResult.get(content.getUrl()).getData().getParseMeta();
    byte[] rawContent = content.getContent();
    String str = new String(rawContent, "UTF-8");
    metadata.add("rawcontent", str);
        return parseResult;
}
```

After that, change your schema.xml and add the new field:

```
<field name="metatag.rawcontent" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Compile, deploy, re-crawl, re-index.

You should now see raw HTML content in your SOLR index.

Note: --

Make sure you have enabled [metatags plugins](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags). This is important because you are essentially storing rawcontent as the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nutch 2.1 with Cassandra backend, or Mysql ( it has some bugs ), or HBase. Then you will be able to make Queries in the database, and obtain all html code from pages.